# conditionally assign var with check for defined and condtion

Tags: shell-script, variable

I want to assign a variable conditionally.

This does not work

```
[[ -v $2]] && [$2 == "init" ] && command="./ops/init.sh"
[[ -v $2]] && [$2 == "destroy" ] && command="./ops/teardown.sh"
[ -z "${2}" ] && command="./ops/help.sh -h"
```

I am trying check for the existence of the argument and another conditon but I cannot get the syntax right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with `-v` is a zsh extension, so your issue might be just that the wrong shell is executing your script.

The normal way to write this would be to use a case statement.

```
case "$2" in
    ("init") command="./ops/init.sh" ;;
    ("destroy") command="./ops/teardown.sh" ;;
    ("") command="./ops/help.sh -h" ;;
    (*) echo "$0: unknown option '$2' - expecting 'init' or 'destroy'" >&2
        exit 2 ;;
esac
```

It is not the best idea to put multiple words into a string as in `./ops/help.sh -h` although you will get away with it (and had no choice originally with the shell). Instead consider using an array.

Answer (score 0):

In shell scripting you need to be very careful about whitespace. You also should be aware of [the differences between `[` and `[[`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031). If unsure, consult the bash(1) manual. I recommend [shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) to detect common mistakes in your scripts. In your case:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
[[ -v $2 && $2 = "init" ]] && command="./ops/init.sh"
[[ -v $2 && $2 = "destroy" ]] && command="./ops/teardown.sh"
[[ -z $2 ]] && command="./ops/help.sh -h"
```

But as icarus said a `case` statement is preferable.